# What does the '>' do?

Tags: linux

What does        `ls > list` and         `ls >> list`         do?  They don't seem to do anything on my system.

Comment: Checkout: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html  basicly > redirects output of command, >> also redirect but append.

Comment: Start with what finding out what `ls` does. Then apply that before and after running the commands presented.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls > list
```

Creates a new file named **list** and adds the contents of `ls` command into that file.

You can check the contents of the file **list** by typing the command as,

```
cat list
```

Now, for the second command,

```
ls >> list
```

It will append the contents of the `ls` command to the file named **list**. So the difference would be if you execute this command 5 times, the output of `ls` command would be written 5 times to the **list** file but for the first command each and every time, the output would be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making

`ls > list`

and then

`ls >> list`

you can see the difference by just typing

`cat list`

after each time.